# Create new array of array with objects that have objects inside, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects that looks like this

```
var array = [
{car : {id:123}, count: 2, rule: {id:55, color: "red"}},
{car : {id:456}, count: 5, rule: {id:15, color: "blue"}},
{car : {id:883}, count: 1, rule: {id:557, color: "green"}}
...
];
```

Array is array of objects, car is object with id, rule is object with id and color.

I want to loop through array and create new array that will look like this

```
var newArray = [
{carId : 123, count:2, ruleId:55},
{carId : 456, count:5, ruleId:15},
{carId : 883, count:1, ruleId:557}
]
```

So I want to pull values from objects that are inside objects of my object array.

If is possible I would like to this with ES5 or ES6, using Array.map or Array.forEach.

Comment: This is exactly what Array.map does.  As a general recommendation, at Stack Overflow you should at least make a minimum effort to solve the task yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: It is possible with `Array.prototype.map` but with forEach is also possible give it a try and let us know how it goes

Comment: `var res = array.map((elem) => {
return {carId: elem.car.id, count: elem.count, ruleId: elem.rule.id}
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a map you will easyly obtain what you ecpect :

```js
var array = [
{car : {id:123}, count: 2, rule: {id:55, color: "red"}},
{car : {id:456}, count: 5, rule: {id:15, color: "blue"}},
{car : {id:883}, count: 1, rule: {id:557, color: "green"}}
];
var newArray = array.map(x => ({carId: x.car.id, count: x.count, ruleId: x.rule.id})) ;

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating a new array via [map()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9qYPDw4rRAhVJ1oMKHTYsD0wQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=zEfgF86jTxNCnEOIjgJ6mQ) and from there create a new object in each iteration using the current object's attributes.

```js
var array = [{
  car: {
    id: 123
  },
  count: 2,
  rule: {
    id: 55,
    color: "red"
  }
}, {
  car: {
    id: 456
  },
  count: 5,
  rule: {
    id: 15,
    color: "blue"
  }
}, {
  car: {
    id: 883
  },
  count: 1,
  rule: {
    id: 557,
    color: "green"
  }
}];

var newArray = array.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    carId: obj['car']['id'],
    count: obj['count'],
    ruleId: obj['rule']['id']
  };
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: I don't think that `Object.create()` is necessary. You can just return the object literal.

Comment: Good call. Updated my answer to become a little more terse.